# как правильно построить запрос на выборку из Бд ? Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.8

Как получить курсы, которые имеют 'title' = 'english' и определенный город к примеру 'Москва'

вот как получить по названию можно так а вот как еще учитывать и город?

$paginator = Course::where('title', $courses)->orderBy('order')->paginate(9);
отношение таблиц Laravel,

если 2 модели Сity и School имеют между собой многие ко многим, а модели Course связаны многие ко многим с School

```
class City extends Model
{   
      public function schools()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\School');
  }
}
class School extends Model
{   
   public function cities()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\City');
  }
  public function courses()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course');
  }
}

class Course extends Model
{

  public function schools()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\School');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Приблизительно вот так:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

Course::where('title', 'english')->whereHas('schools.cities', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('name', 'Москва');
})->get();
```

Comment: спасибо, работает, а не подскажите почему переменная не передается

Comment: `function (Builder $query) use ($city) {
    $query->where('name', $city);
}`

Comment: спасибо большое